# Angular momentum in a centrifuge

Tags: angular-momentum, centrifugal-force

Just a curiosity, centrifuges are ideally perfectly balanced, but can tolerate some level of imbalance. Is this due to the angular momentum of the rotor residing rapid oscillations in tilt? How would I figure or the relative force differences between an imbalanced centrifuge providing force to tilt (and break) a centrifuge vs. the angular momentum of the rotor that is resistant to said tilt?

Answer (score 0):

An imbalance will stress the bearings, but imbalance is not in a position to cause tilt.

The force that arises due to the imbalance is pounding the bearings, but as far as tilt is concerned the rapid rotation makes the imbalance-induced-force average out.

In that sense the angular momentum of the centrifuge is not a factor in being able to to cope with imbalance